# Swift: IBoutlet always returns nil object?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

I have UItableView with Custom UItableViewCell with its nib file.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(quoteCellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath) as DynamicTableViewCell

    if (cell == nil)
    {
        println("Not Initialized")
    }
    println(cell)
    println(cell.scenarioLabel)

    return cell
}
```

**Console O/p**

```
<_TtC17Dynamic_Cell_Demo20DynamicTableViewCell: 0xb291a70; baseClass = UITableViewCell; frame = (0 0; 320 44); layer = <CALayer: 0xb291e40>>

For Lable : null
```

Custom UITableViewCell

```
class DynamicTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

@IBOutlet var scenarioLabel: UILabel
@IBOutlet var quoteContentLabel: UILabel
```

**Connection**

[image]

Comment: check is outlet is Connected ?

Comment: try cell.scenarioLabel.text

Comment: @Yatheesha its perfect..

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik nope bad access

Comment: @Yatheesha let me show you screenshot. Check question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are not registered nib in tableview, try this in `-viewDidLoad`

In Swift :

```
tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "DynamicTableViewCell", bundle:nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: quoteCellIdentifier)
```

In Objective-C:

```
[self.tableView registerNib:[UINib nibWithNibName:@"DynamicTableViewCell"
                         bundle:nil]]
         forCellReuseIdentifier: quoteCellIdentifier];
```

Comment: @AshishKakkad Updated to Swift.

Comment: @Yatheesha Good. +1 For it

Answer (score 1):

according to @yatheesha answer i am just converting into swift language

```
var dynCellQuote = UINib(nibName: "DynamicTableViewCell", bundle: nil)

    tableViewForQuotes.registerNib(dynCellQuote, forCellReuseIdentifier: quoteCellIdentifier)
```

Comment: You don't need the intermediate variable `dynCellQuote`, and if you want it anyhow you don't need to specify its type (`:UINib`), and it would also be better as a constant (`let` instead of `var`) as it's not re-assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You may get this error when your class name is generic class name like TabBarViewController. Not in your case, but I got this error in that case.